# Sweetalert Appearing behind of asp ModalPopupExtender

Tags: css

I am using `ModalPopupExtender` for popup. For displaying alert message i am using `Sweetalert` custom popup everything is fine but while displaying custom message, My `Sweetalert` popup is appearing behind of modal popup.

I remove `Z-index` from my `ModalPopupExtender` but still same thing I am getting.

I tried :

```
 .swal-container {
            z-index: 10000;
        }
```

Popup Style:

```
.Popup {
            background-color: #FFFFFF;
            border-width: 3px;
            border-style: solid;
            border-color: black;
            padding-top: 10px;
            padding-left: 10px;
            width: 950px;
            height: 240px;
            /*z-index: 1100;*/
        }
```

Comment: It's not easy to debug unless we see your output.

Comment: @m4n0 you mean i have to add jsfiddle for that ?

Comment: Whichever code platform that you prefer.

Comment: @m4n0 ok i will add that fidler